# Uploading ASP.net & Angular application on Tomcat server

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, asp.net-web-api

I have just finished the local development of my Web API (ASP.net) and the User interface (AngularJs) and I would like to put it in a Tomcat server. I really need help getting this done.

I really have no ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Tomcat is for Java-based applications and will not work. If you are on Linux you would use something like nginx or apache. If you are on windows, you would setup your ASP.NET Core site in IIS or as a windows service. If you have the option, I recommend hosting on a cloud provider such as Azure.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer now I know how to do it.